# Can I modify model.currentuser to my current username which is logged in the system as its value is set by default while getting IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, identityserver3

[enter image description here][1]Link to the code from Identityserver which I need to modify
            https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/DefaultViewService/EmbeddedAssetsViewService/templates/permissions.html

```
 I need to see the login page with current user's Id when the login page appears so I want to set a value in ng-init field with model.currentuser which should be current user's Id
```

I tried setting username to a default value as model.logoutUrl and this value is reflected in username when I login into Identity Server.

But,if I try to get current user's Id ,I dont find any value in username of login page in Identity Server .It's because model.currentUser is st to null.I want to set this value.Where can I set this value as Identity server code is auto-generated

Username

I need current user's Id to be populated in login screen of identity server

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKFCa.png  -Image of login page from Identity server

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                                            <input contenteditable="true" name="username" autofocus id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-init="model.username = model.username || model.logoutUrl" ng-model="model.username" maxlength="100">
                                        </div> I tried this and this populates login screen with logout url when login page loads first time

Comment: But when I use model.currentUser instead,I don't get any value in Username in login screen. I found that this value is not assigned to current user's id.Can someone suggest where i assign model.currentUser this value as it self generated code from identity server in html file

Comment: Any hints if anyone can provide?